# Not able to present Google user image insde Google workspace addon

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm working on a [Google Workspace Addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-workspace-addons) using TS & Express.
When trying to display an image coming from my CDN, I see that google caches/proxies it via its own URL
i.e

```
https://www.lorempixel.com/400/400
```

turns into

```
https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1A6QM0...bvtAcYz6o8U7e622Nu7Uq4=s40
```

But when trying to present an image that's coming from Google (i.e google account image), it's not proxied, and the actual URL is passed, with just a `=s40` suffix to it.
i.e

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh1...%3Ds96-c
```

turns into

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh1...%3Ds96-c=s40
```

which breaks the URL and presents a broken image...
was wondering if anyone encountered this?
and if i can save the user's google image as a profile image in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by broken? What is the actual error? Yes, you can use a Google user's profile picture. Enter the URL in the browser and the image will display. Your code is doing something to transform/break the URL. Use the Chrome debugger to see the URL your code is presenting and then compare that to the original URl.

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley, My code is not transforming any of the URL's, I pass a regular URL (the one I get from google, which works perfectly)
but it seems like google appends a `=s40` suffix when it's rendered inside the workspace addon